# How much below adjacent paver stones should artificial grass be?

Tags: landscaping, hard-landscape

Reading instructions for artificial grass installation, it talks about digging 4 inches of dirt before applying the base layer and then installing the synthetic grass.

My question is when all is said and done (gravel base, weed fabric, leveled), how much below the adjacent stone pavers should the base of the synthetic grass be for proper aesthetics and containment of infill?  should it be just below grade enough to contain the infill?  Is that 1/4"?  1/2"?  How much grass should be poking above grade compared to the adjacent stone patio?

I'm using a synthetic grass with 1.65" of pile.

Answer (score 1):

Flush, if not a bit higher than the stones.

To avoid nasty toe grabs and broken nails if barefoot, or silly looking stumbles when walking with your arms full, try and make it as close, if not s tough higher than the stones. The spongey-nature of the grass will sink a bit when stepped upon, so consider this when installing.